# What are the differences when casting from integer to char array in following ways in C?

Tags: c, casting, char, type-conversion, printf

I am casting from integers to char arrays in the following ways, but I don't understand what are the differences when using print (since in both I am printing char arrays?):

```
// The desired output is always "65" literal and NOT "A"
// First way:
char a = (char)65;
printf("%d", a); // "65"


// Second way:
char str[3];
sprintf(str, "%d\n", 65);
printf("str: %s\n", str); // "65"
```

However, the following ways return errors:

```
// Note that I am exchanging only the format in the printf function
printf("%s", a); // Error
printf("str: %d\n", str); // Error
```

Comment: The format specifier (`%d`, etc.) tells `printf` what to interpret the varargs parameters as. `%s` is equal to `char*`. So you are telling `printf` to start reading string data (char array) from address `65`. That address is not allocated to your process, and thus the error. The second line is not an error (`printf("str: %d\n", str);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid conversion specifiers for objects outputted in calls of printf.

In this call

```
printf("%s", a);
```

the conversion specifier `%s` expects an argument of the type `char *` while you are passing an object of the type `char`.

In this call

```
printf("str: %d\n", str);
```

the conversion specifier `%d` expects an argument of the type `int` while you are passing an expression of the type `char *` to which the array designator is implicitly converted.

As for example for this code snippet

```
char a = (char)65;
printf("%d", a);
```

then here is the casting of the integer constant `65` to the type `char` is redundant.

You may write

```
char a = 65;
```

In the call of printf you are using the conversion specifier `%d` that outputs the character as an integer. That is it outputs the internal representation of the ASCII character 'A'. If you will use the conversion specifier `%c` instead of `%d` you will get as the output the symbol `'A'`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Just one question: `printf("%s", a);` Here `a` is a `char` when `%s` is expecting a char pointer. But I thought that char array can be automatically casted into char *?

Comment: @MiguelWang Arrays in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements. But in your example a is not an array. It is a scalar object of the type char. Moreover the conversion specifier %s expects that the pointer used as an argument points to a string.